# How to save a variable to the server using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii, webrtc

I am implementing a video conference room and I have a variable (room_status) which holds the status of the room (0 = close & 1 = open). Now this variable is only accessible my the client who clicks open-room.

I need to save the room_status variable to the server so that it can be accessed on other client's side. Here is a piece of my code:

```
var room_status = 0; //room closed

$('#open-room').click(function () {
    // http://www.rtcmulticonnection.org/docs/open/
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "../invite",
        data: {
            videoconference_id: $('#meetingID').val(),
            invitee_id: 1111,
            status: "Accepted"
        },
        success: function() {
            alert("success!");
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("fail");
        }
    });

    //room_status = 1; //room opened
    rmc.open();
    rmc.streams.mute({video : true});
    document.getElementById("on-off-video").style.color= 'red';
});

$('#join-room').click(function () {
    if(room_status) {
        // http://www.rtcmulticonnection.org/docs/connect/
        rmc.connect();
        rmc.streams.mute({video: true});
        document.getElementById("on-off-video").style.color= 'red';
    } else {
        console.log("Waiting for meeting organizer");
    }

});
```

Comment: The answer will be: **use ajax**, $.ajax(),$.post(),$.get().  I think you need more than that, if you already have the backend then you should provide it here so we can know what to send. If don't then you should ask in a backend category how to.

Answer (score 2):

Ajax is your friend.
Here is an example from a prject of mine with jquery ui :

```
function prepare_ajax_button(l){
    $("#button").button().click(function(event,ui){
        $.ajax({type: "GET",data: {"arg1":l},url: "update_variable.php",success: function(data){
            alert("Success ?!");
        },error: function(data){alert("Problem ?!");}});
    });
}
```

The page "update_variable.php" can for instance write the variable in a text file, mysql...

Comment: Is there something wrong with this code? I am getting fail... 

$.ajax({

            type: 'GET',

            url: "../invite",

            data: {

                videoconference_id: $('#meetingID').val(),

                invitee_id: 1111,

                status: "Accepted"

            },

            success: function() {

                alert("success!");

            },

            error: function() {

                alert("fail");
            }
        });

Comment: Look at the JavaScript console: Is there a more useful error message? Look at the Net tab of the developer tools: Does the server return a 200OK response?

Comment: I just edited my question to reflect what I added. Is there anything wrong with that ajax piece. I am getting fail...